# Mac Charts Project fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff88f43128)

Tags: swift, macos, ios-charts

I have two projects: an iOS project using iOS Charts that plots the data without any problems and a Mac companion app that fails when assinging the data to the `lineChartView.data` object. I also get a warning:

> 'warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.'

Here is my code:

```
let values = (0..<count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
    let value = recordingpoints[i]
    return ChartDataEntry(x:Double(i), y: value)
}

let data = LineChartData()
let dataset = LineChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Glucose Trends")
data.addDataSet(dataset)
self.lineChartView.data = data
```

I cannot find where the error is generated. Here is a screenshot of the error:
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxLNt.png)

Comment: Is there any more text to the error message?  Can you set a breakpoint and step through the code to see exactly which line it breaks on?

Comment: That’s all it displays for the error. I set a break point the last line where data is assigned and try to step through the process but it gets into assembler code and I get lost.

Comment: Interesting development: just stepped through the code, still got the error but not the warning. Ran it again without the break points and got the same results: error but no warning.

Comment: You show the warning message only, can you show your error log from Xcode console?

Comment: There is none only the red EXC_BAD_ACCESS I’ll post an image if possible